# HAL support in Rest-Assured

Tags: spring-data-rest, rest-assured

I use Spring-Data-Rest (SDR) to create a REST-Service.
For integation tests I use Rest Assured (RA).

The problem arises when I try to send a domain object via RA to the service.
Relations are expressed via links and my domain objects do not have links, just related entities.

Is there any JsonMapper for RA which translates the related entities into links?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No there's no such thing built into Rest Assured. What you could to do is to create a [filter](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#filters) that does this for you (but I'm not sure how easy or hard this would be).